# Muon Package mgr will not update packages, cautious upgrade grayed out, bug reporter not functional

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, discover-software-center, muon-package-manager

Kubuntu 22.04 KDE 5.92.0
Muon Package Manager ver. 5.8.0       New install...
Muon will not get updates, the sparing times that it did, the cautious upgrade would be grayed out, full upgrade is grayed out. The only button that seems to work is check for updates. I did have Kubuntu open the PPA's for me when installing. I tried fixing Muon this way.

```
sudo apt update
```

sudo apt-get purge muon
sudo apt-get install muon

It still does not work. I also used terminal to check for updates, it says there are none.
It is worth mentioning that Discover updates will also not work,at all. There is one update there called - unifying receiver RQR12.11_B0032 but it will not install it.
While I was looking at these things, and earlier about the first 24 hours of the install a nagging update, I think from admin or system, about language packs needing to be installed. I went ahead and told it to install these language packs, then continued looking for the Muon and Discover update problem. I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue and a fix. It is very interesting that the bug reporter will not even work in Muon.

Does this action below ever try to upgrade the Operating System and replace proprietary Nvidia with open source drivers?
-I usually open a terminal & just run sudo apt update & scan output (all lines are there, no warnings/errors), then sudo apt full-upgrade (or apt upgrade if you avoid full-upgrade)

Update: (I'm thinking that Kubuntu 22.04 does not update very often as I have experienced with other distros and it is possible these programs are acting this way because there are NO updates)

Comment: I rarely used the user tools of `muon` or *KDE Discover*, but if I do and I have problems there, I usually open a terminal & just run `sudo apt update` & scan output (*all lines are there, no warnings/errors*), then `sudo apt full-upgrade` (or `apt upgrade` if you avoid `full-upgrade`) and note messages there. It should run the same processes as the package tools you mention, but messages are shown on terminal & thus I have something to act on (eg. I maybe told to try `sudo apt -f install` etc).  I'll suggest you try terminal too.  Bug reporter should work if your system is all good.

Comment: Excellent, does that action ever try to replace the proprietary nvidia drivers? I had a problem with that on Studio. It is specifically Muon bug reporter not working. If this works, I will learn to use terminal on everything.

Comment: No action should cause the *removal* of another package, except if the package was a problem due to how it was packaged (*usually 3rd party packages built not for a specific release, but for many systems thus problems can be expected on some of them*). You have full control of terminal commands, unless you opt to not use it (eg. use `-y` to accept any consequences being the main reason for issues).  There is nothing wrong with GUI or front-end tools (`muon`, *KDE Discover* etc; we include them with Lubuntu too!) and all Ubuntu should be equivalent (ie. Kubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Lubuntu..)

Comment: but I just find the terminal easier at times, especially if there are problems. If you use front-end tools like `muon` etc. you need to go searching in logs for cause/problems; where as on terminal they appear as messages on screen - ie. easier to find!!   Use whatever works for you; each has *pros* & *cons*, terminal package commands has the *pro* of showing all messages (*these can be scary at times, thus that maybe a con too*)

Comment: To be clear, I don't want it to upgrade my system and nvidia drivers,  just the packages. And if I'm you understanding correctly, it won't do that, but if it did, it would tell me, so I could decline that action?

Comment: As long as you don't use `-y` in your `apt` commands, you're asked to accept any changes required.. The `-y` is used to answer YES to all changes, which is how users often get into problems, they copy & paste from sites online a command that includes `-y` & thus accept the damage they should have read & then declined.   Yes, you have full control.  eg. I don't have `ubuntu-budgie-desktop` installed on my box; so I opened terminal & entered `sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop`  and it lists the changes and `175 to newly install` then asks me "*Do you want to continue? [Y/n]*" .. I decline

Comment: FYI:  I can view the same detail I saw in the terminal command mentioned in last comment in MUON, it's just presented differently in the DEPENDENCIES TAB... 175 lines of output I can scroll thru in `muon` contrasted to 175 packages listed with a space between on terminal...  They're different ways to achieve the same thing..   `muon` has extra detail that would require extra options at terminal than my provided command.. but one isn't better than the other... we just have alterantives.

Comment: All Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system receive upgrades the same way; which includes all *flavors* at the same time (ie. Kubuntu is no different to any other Ubuntu system).  Updates are published many places, eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue803#Ubuntu_22.04_Updates shows the updates within the last week... but you'll only receive upgrades to packages installed on your system, ie. a Kubuntu 22.04 LTS system receives the identical upgrades to a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system where the same packages are included.. Kubuntu install media differs on what is installed by default the only diff.

Comment: I feel confident using the terminal for updates now. I will use terminal for updates. If you read my updated question, I think the problem was, there are no updates available. Why Muon would not let me open a bug report matters none to me. This problem is solved, IMO.